# EditText to int using Integer.parseInt

Tags: android

I'm new to programming and Android.  I'm making my best attempt at a simple app and I'm stuck!

I have two editTexts (set to accept numbers only) and a button.  The idea is to display the sum of the two user inputs when the button is pressed.  However, my app stops working and force closes when I click the button in the emulator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prevailing_torque);
    Button calculatePrevailing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calculatePrevailing);


    calculatePrevailing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView prevailingSetting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSetting);
            EditText editTextPrevailing = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrevailing);
            EditText editTextRecommended = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextReccomended);

            int p = Integer.parseInt(editTextPrevailing.getText().toString());
            int r = Integer.parseInt(editTextRecommended.getText().toString());

            prevailingSetting.setText(r+p);
        }
    });
}
```

I've looked at several similar questions on here but I haven't been able to find anything that I can implement further than what I have already done.  But I am probably looking in the wrong places.
Thanks!

Comment: paste the error log here

Comment: Welcome to SO! What error is it throwing in LogCat? Try: .setText(Integer.toString(r+p))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use setText() with an Integer since it expects a CharSequence, you have to use

```
prevailingSetting.setText(String.valueOf(r+p));
```

or just

```
prevailingSetting.setText(""+(r+p));
```

Comment: Thank you!  The first bit works great.  The second returns 10+20=1020.

Comment: yeah you actually have to do the math first, so it would be prevailingSetting.setText(""+(r+p));

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prevailing_torque);
   Button calculatePrevailing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calculatePrevailing);
   TextView prevailingSetting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSetting);
   EditText editTextPrevailing = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrevailing);
   EditText editTextRecommended =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextReccomended);

   calculatePrevailing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int p = Integer.parseInt(editTextPrevailing.getText().toString());
        int r = Integer.parseInt(editTextRecommended.getText().toString());
        int s = r+p;
        prevailingSetting.setText(Integer.toString(s));


    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! if  this is your problem then first of all convert your editText value to string and after that convert it into integer like !

```
 String str1=editTextPrevailing.getText().toString();
 String str2=editTextRecommended.getText().toString();
 int p = Integer.parseInt(str1);
  int r = Integer.parseInt(str2);
  int s = r+p;
   prevailingSetting.setText(""+s);
```